# Cannot serve request to /bin/wcmcommand in com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.commands.WCMCommandServlet

Tags: aem

I happened to write a launcher which is using a custom process written in java. Everything works fine until I start the workflow on any page. When I see the payload path in the workflow console I see it as "/bin/wcmcommand?cmd=open&path=%252Fcontent%252Fsample&*charset*=utf-8.html" and on opening the payload I get the error like "Cannot serve request to /bin/wcmcommand in com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.commands.WCMCommandServlet" . Don't know what is wrong with this. Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: The logs should tell you what's wrong, maybe using DEBUG log level if the standard levels don't provide enough information.

Answer (score 1):

This wcmcommand servlet only accepts POST call. You are making the GET call. So its not understanding the request. Please call using POST METHOD Class.
If you want to call in Java class then call from servlet class like this

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/bin/wcmcommand").include(slingrequest, slingresponse);
```

This will work for your customization